# Regular Expression - Should not allow whitespaces continuously

Tags: java, regex, spring

In my web application, I have text box where the user should enter characters ranging from 5 to 200 characters.

The problem is - when the user eneter 5 whitespaces continuously and saves the entry, it is getting saved successfully.

I should BLOCK the user to enter the 'whitespaces' continously (or white spaces alone).

But I can allow single whitespace (like 'customer table', customer   table').

But I can allow the user to enter white spaces with character. Also I dont want the name starting with space.

Can anyone please help me in getting the REGEX for the above condition?

Comment: `"\\s{2,}"` matches 2 or more white-space characters. You can obviously change that to 5 or whatever you want.

Comment: This sounds like a job for String.trim(), rather than regexp.

Comment: I am using Spring Roo. So I have to use REGEX alone in my domain class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^\S+(\s\S+)*$`

This regexp should do what you want. It accepts non-empty strings starting with and ending with non-whitespace characters, and only with a single whitespace between words.

You should check for total string length separately.

Note that you need to escape the \ in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Starts with a space or contains more than 2 continuous spaces:

```
^\s|\s{2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create two patterns
One `^\s` and the other `\s{2,}` and if either one matches then reject the string
Alternatively use `{2,}` if you want to disallow something like empty space and a newline matching together but you shouldn't have a new line in there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `"\\s{2,}"` with `" "`, then replace all `"^\\s+|\\s+$"` with `""` (or search and reject if those are found, depending on your logic).